# How can I transfer data to other database in SQLServer 2000!

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have two Database, DB1 and DB2. How can I transfer data of DB1
specific table to DB2 in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using DTS?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this through code (the .NET tag), then `SqlBulkCopy` is your friend -ideally when mixed with `ExecuteReader` on the source. [Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565732/copy-from-one-database-table-to-another-c/565830#565830):

```
using (SqlConnection connSource = new SqlConnection(csSource)) // source db
using (SqlCommand cmd = connSource.CreateCommand())
using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(csDest)) { // destination db
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; // destination table
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Foo]"; // source table
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    connSource.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on DB2 and Tasks-> Import will start the DTS Wizard. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional context about this transfer would be useful. For example, is this a one-off transfer, a regular transfer, something you want to maintain for each transaction in DB1 or something else.

I'm going to assume this is a one-off or periodic occurance and, as such, I'd suggest 
Data Transformation Services (DTS) in SQL Server 2000:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx