# Creating batched sql statements

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, batch-file

I have a small job that takes a text file of email/zip codes and inserts them into a sql server 2005 table. It reads each line of the source file, checks to make sure that it parses into a valid email address/zip code, creates a sql insert command, adds it to a string builder and eventually executes it. I want to do a single execute instead of individual sql calls as there will possibly be several thousand inserts.

This works, but I'd like to know if this is a bad approach. What's the best practice here?

```
Dim SqlString As String = "insert into [CollectedEmail] values('{0}','{1}');"

Do Until sourceFile.Peek = -1
        line = sourceFile.ReadLine
        If line.Length > 0 Then

            Dim emailAddress As String = Trim(line.Substring(0, EmailLength))
            Dim zipcode As String = Trim(line.Substring(EmailLength + 2, ZipCodeLength))

            If CVal.validEmail(emailAddress) AndAlso CVal.validZip(zipcode) Then
                SQL.AppendLine(String.Format(SqlString, emailAddress, zipcode))
            ElseIf CVal.validEmail(emailAddress) Then
               SQL.AppendLine(String.Format(SqlString, emailAddress, ""))
            Else
                badAddresses.WriteLine(emailAddress)
            End If
        End If

    Loop
 InsertToDatabase(SQL.ToString)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bulk inserts, check out .NET 2.0 onwards, [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class (in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace)

Marc Gravell posted an example of its use here on SO: [Copy from one database table to another C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565732/copy-from-one-database-table-to-another-c)

**Updated in response to comment**: you can read the cleansed data into a `DataTable`, and use that with `SqlBulkCopy`, similiar to this [example](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/03/08/2877.aspx).

Comment: Is the correct approach then to cleanse the original source file into another flat file and then use the SqlBulkCopy class?

Answer (score 0):

If you have sql server 2008 then you can use Table-Valued Parameters, see here for some more info [Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) and sample code. Otherwise do bulk insert

Answer (score 0):

You could also bundle your emails into an XML parameter and have some stored procedure that is able to process it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[saveEmails]
(   
    @emails xml
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


insert into collectedemail
(address
,zipcode)
select
x.value('address[1]', 'nvarchar(255)')
,x.value('zipcode[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')  
from @emails.nodes('/items/item') emails(x)

END
GO
```

You can keep a counter that stores how many records you have queued up and then execute after a batch size you specify.